# QT, C++, Linux и Vim

Tags: c++, linux, qt, vim

Недавно решил перейти к изучению С++ и QT (до этого изучал Си) и хотел прояснить несколько вещей для себя. Прошу не ругать меня строго, так как я только-только начинаю: всего-то пока скачал книгу Прата по С++, а про QT знаю только по страничке в Википедии.

Вообщем:

1) Что нужно для программирования с помощью QT на линуксе?

2) Нужен ли для этого обязательно QTCreator?

3) Вопрос вытекает из предыдущих двух: можно ли использовать QT пользуясь vim-ом в качестве редактора, clang-ом для компиляции и make-ом для сборки проектов?

Не то, чтобы я априори не любил IDE, но мне больше нравится другой вариант (чисто субъективно). Программирование для меня просто хобби.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Что нужно для программирования с помощью QT на линуксе?

Минимальный набор стандартен: компилятор, редактор, собственно Qt с его инструментами (`moc`, `uic`, `qmake`), хедерами и прочей dev-мишурой и, конечно, собственные знания.

Кроме того желательно:

- Высокоуровневая система сборки с поддержкой Qt (можно и вручную писать Makefile'ы, но это дело тем менее благодарное, чем сложнее организация проекта); основные варианты:

  - `qmake`, родной, требует минимального изучения, но не универсальный и не очень гибкий
  - `cmake`, универсальный, требует отдельного (хотя бы минимального) изучения.
  - `Autotools` — инструмент матёрых GNU'шников. Сложен.
- Если нет желания прописывать создание формочек в коде, а пользоваться Qt'шным генератором то крайне желателен `designer`.
- Плагины для редактора в меру своей испорченности. Для автодополнения vim/плюсов хороша будет комбинация YCM+clang+cmake.
- Отладчик. Если с голым `gdb` чувствуешь себя комфортно/готов разбираться, то его хватит. Если нет, то придётся пользоваться IDE т.к. *нормального* лёгкого гуя к нему не существует. Также крайне полезно [стащить](https://cgit.kde.org/kdevelop.git/tree/plugins/gdb/printers?) из `kdevelop` pretty-printer'ы для Qt.

> Нужен ли для этого обязательно QTCreator?

Нет.

> Вопрос вытекает из предыдущих двух: можно ли использовать QT пользуясь vim-ом в качестве редактора, clang-ом для компиляции и make-ом для сборки проектов?

Да. С оговорками про `make`.

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли использовать QT пользуясь vim-ом в качестве редактора, clang-ом для компиляции и make-ом для сборки проектов?

Да, причём спокойно. Единственное, что вам потребуется — это:

- заголовочные (`.h`) файлы,
- динамические библиотеки самого Qt,
- статические библиотеки, чтобы можно было при компоновке добавить импорты из вышеуказанных динамических библиотек.

Также существует несколько утилит, необходимость в которых зависит исключительно от используемых вами возможностей Qt:

- `moc` — если у вас есть прямые или косвенные наследники от `QObject`, в теле которых встречаются сущности вида `Q_*` (`Q_OBJECT`, `Q_INVOKABLE` и т. д.), вам надо пропустить через эту утилиту `.hpp`-файлы с объявлением этих классов. На выходе будет дополнительный `.cpp`-файл, который надо скормить компоновщику вместе с остальными.
- `rcc` — если у вас есть файлы ресурсов (`.rc`), то их тоже надо преобразовать в `.cpp` с помощью этой утилиты.
- `uic` — всё то же самое, только для файлов Qt Designer (`.ui`).

Это, по сути, необходимый минимум для использования Qt. Всё остальное — лишь упрощающая жизнь обвязка поверх этой базы.

То есть вы можете спокойно пользоваться `make`, вызывая все эти утилиты из `Makefile` вручную. Например так:

```
# * win_main.o — получен из win_main.cpp
# * win_main_ui.o — получен из win_main.ui

your_app: win_main.o win_main_ui.o
    # Вызов компоновщика

%.o: %.cpp
    # Вызов компилятора

%_ui.cpp: %.ui
    uic -o "$@" $^
```