# Как использовать Qt в C++ без QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt

Как я могу использовать Qt без QtCreator?

Я только начал знакомиться с C++, поэтому мне не очевидно что я должен скачать и подключить, что бы самостоятельно компилировать приложения с Qt. У меня есть windows 7, g++ и другие компоненты MinGW, cmake и мой текстовый редактор. Я не нашел гайдов о том, где мне взять заголовочные и другие файлы Qt или хотя бы как это называется.

Везде описывается только разработка в QtCreator, который неплох, но мне совершенно не нужен. Подскажите где взять SDK Qt и куда его ложить.

Сейчас при попытке сборки, cmake ругается так:

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
> qt5widgets-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.

Кстати, я правильно понимаю, что если мне понадобится глобальная видимость заголовочных файлов (например для того, что бы использовать их в разных проектах без копирования), я могу скопировать их куда-то в cmake? Или нужно в MinGW? На этот вопрос не обязательно отвечать, он просто к месту.

Comment: сам Qt уже собрал/установил? с помощью cmake'а в своём окружении собирать умеешь?

Comment: @Fat-Zer установил Qt с офсайта, раздела /download. Сейчас могу использовать Qt только из QtCreator'а. Пока что ничего не пробовал собирать, если вопрос о разработке. Ну а попросить mingw32-make собрать что-нибудь могу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [QT, C++, Linux и Vim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776462/qt-c-linux-%d0%b8-vim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено

> Как я могу использовать Qt без QtCreator?

Всё просто, нужно скомпилировать Qt из исходников. Большинство задач покрывается QtBase.

Можно  использовать официальный установщик, что бы поставить необходимые компоненты, но у меня возникли проблемы с этим вариантом. [Онлайн](https://www.qt.io/download) инсталятор выдавал непонятную ошибку соединения на первом шаге установки, а [оффлайн](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers) версия принудительно устанавливает QtCreator.

Итак, сборка QtBase занимает примерно 3 часа на среднем ПК с Win7. Если это тебя не остановит или нужна не стандартная сборка (например статическая или с файлами для отладки), вот что нужно сделать.

- Скачать набор компиляторов MinGW. Например [здесь](http://mingw.org/) или [тут](https://mingw-w64.org)
- Скачать исходные коды Qt с [этой страницы](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)
- Распаковать папку qtbase и выполнить в ней `configure.bat` и `mingw32-make` для сборки

После этого Qt будет установлена в директорию по умолчанию. Советую после установки Qt так же собрать и установить QtDesigner, для удобного и быстрого конструирования стандартных окон. Он находится в директории `qttools`, для конфигурирования нужен `qmake`, который находится в поддиректории `bin`, установленной Qt.

Важно упомянуть, что для корректной сборки на windows, при конфигурировании необходимо использовать параметр `-opengl desktop`, в противном случае, обязательно должен быть установлен [ANGLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/angle), иначе компиляция будет прервана сообщением об ошибке.

Так же, если нужно изменить директорию установки Qt, можно использовать параметр `--prefix`

В общем случае, для конфигурации Makefile достаточно выполнить следующую команду

```
configure.bat --prefix=C:\Qt\MyBuild -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

Описать в деталях как пользоваться `cmake`'ом на win-платформе я не смогу, так что дам в общих чертах последовательность действий:

- Cоздаёшь `CMakeLists.txt`, за основу можно взять [это](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html):

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
  project(testproject)

  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

  find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

  set(helloworld_SRCS
      mainwindow.ui
      mainwindow.cpp
      main.cpp
  )

  add_executable(helloworld ${helloworld_SRCS})
  target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets)
  ```

  `main.cpp` и `mainwindow.{cpp,h}` пишешь в своём редакторе, по необходимости форму `mainwindow.ui` создаёшь в `designer`'е (идёт вместе с Qt) или, если страдаешь излишней суровостью, то вручную — это xml-файл.
- Создаёшь отдельный каталог сборки (назовём его `build`) и вызываешь в нём

  ```
  cmake путь/к/каталогу/исходников
  ```

  При этом надо сообщить `cmake`'у пути до тулчейна (`gсс`/`g++`/`make`/`ld`) и Qt (на сколько-то уровней вверх от каталога с файлами `Qt*.cmake`, аналогично [`этому описанию`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920132/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba-qt/920239#920239)). Какой предпочтительный/удобный способ сделать и то и другое на win-платформе — я не скажу. Также возможно потребуется передать другие аргументы вроде `-G "MinGW Makefiles"`.
- Смотришь чтобы `cmake` отработал без ошибок, после чего получишь дерево сборки с гоовыми `Makefile`'ами и собираешь их обычной командой:

  ```
  make
  ```

Также в качестве альтернативы, можно пользоваться `qmake`'ом или возможно писать `Makefile`'ы самостоятельно.

Comment: Но где мне взять Qt? Думаю, я должен скачать какую-то библиотеку и распаковать в удобное место. Но я не могу найти её, на офсайте предлагают только инсталятор Qt студии. Возможно в нем уже содержится библиотека, если так, то в какой папке лежат файлы? Или, если библиотеку можно скачать без лишних запчастей, то где? Или хотя бы как это называется? Может быть какой-нибудь QtSDK или что-то в этом роде, что содержит только саму библиотеку и может быть QMake, но не более того. Это основная проблема с которой я столкнулся

Comment: Сейчас при попытке сбора при помощи cmake, стабильно получаю ошибку: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

Comment: @Петр, я не знаю, есть ли готовая сборка Qt отдельно от креатора и прочей мишуры, но то что идёт с креатором почти наверняка включает библиотеку. Ведь если креатор линкует проекты с оной, то значит.,что либа установлена; На вскидку инсталяторы находятся где-то [здесь](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers).... по поводу ошибки — `cmake` говорит в точности, что надо сделать: найти, где лежит `Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` и передать каталог на несколько уровней выше в `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Для Microsoft Visual studio существует аддон в их маркете (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123)
После установки аддона необходимо указать там используемые версии кьют и можно использовать прямо из студии. В самом проекте классы придется разделить на обычные и классы кьют, т.к. им требуется мета-компиляция. Также возможно редактирование файлов форм через QT Designer и все плюшки вроде qt translator и т.п.

Comment: У меня нет Visual studio

Comment: @Петр, интеграция кьют со студией одна из самых простых, надо просто скачать кьют, установить аддон и прописать там путь, гораздо проще разобраться, чем с настройкой мингв, можете попробовать

Comment: Очень жаль, по описанию мне понравился Qt, но если я обязан использовать сторонний софт для работы с этим фреймворком, тогда лучше перейду на что-нибудь попроще, например wxwidgets. Я очень рассчитывал на Qt, но он слишком много требует, слишком монолитный и отбирающий свободу

Comment: @Петр, вы правы, сейчас Qt из простого фреймворка для работы с графикой вырос в большого кроссплатформенного монстра, который предлагает свою среду разработки, свой метакомпилятор и свою экосистему, так что так или иначе для работы вам придется использовать тулсет, предлгаемый кьют. Если вам необходим только гуй, то рассмотреть другие варианты действительно имеет смысл

Answer (score 2):

[SDK берем тут](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)  только я не нашел там сборку под Mingw может лучше взять MSVC компилятор, чтобы не морочится со сборкой qt.
Вам в любом случае понадобится QtDesigner, который входит в состав Creator'a, возможно есть отдельные сборки. Кроме того не уверен, что удастся обойтись без qmake так как он генерирует исходники форм. Посему я бы рекомендовал Использовать инструментарий Qt. Дабы сосредоточится на изучении Qt.

Если Вам не нужен на данном этапе UI, то лучше ограничится средой CodeBloks или VSCode(Но ИМХО Creator или студия были бы лучше, они лучше поддерживают современные стандарты плюсов).

PS Отделяете мух от котлет рекомендую изучать в следуюущем порядке

1. С++
2. cmake
3. UI(qt)

Comment: Все говорят что я должен использовать Visual studio или другие IDE, а так же QtDesigner. Неужели я не могу позволить себе верстать руками и не зависеть от всей этой тонны мусора весящего гигабайты, к которому нужно ещё и привыкать? Как например, с HTML

Comment: Я был на [этой странице](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers) и тоже не нашел ничего полезного, кроме исходного кода. Значит, мне потребуется скомпилировать 700мб исходного кода, для того что бы получить SDK qt без мусора?

Comment: Вчера я скачал исходные коды с той страницы, должен ли я их как-то компилировать или могу поместить папку `qt-everywhere-src-5.12.0.zip\qt-everywhere-src-5.12.0\qtbase\include` в область видимости cmake и всё заработает?

Comment: Верстать руками и без "мусора" это вам другой UI фреймворк нужен

Comment: какой например? Что бы поддерживал wayland и использовал родное окружение системы по максимуму

Comment: Я таких не знаю у Вас слишком жесткие требования

Comment: Решение найдено. Сейчас перечитал этот ответ, впринципе всё верно написано, возможно этот ответ натолкнул меня на правильный путь, спасибо. Но как ответ отмечать не буду, потому что меня интересовало как я могу установить/собрать нужные компоненты. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ